# Google-Cloud-Dataflow: Can't pull image from ARTIFACT REGISTRY

Tags: go, templates, google-cloud-dataflow, google-artifact-registry

When I try to use dataflow to run the flex template, the job log reports an error。

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Get XXXXXXXXXXX  denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I tried to pull the image locally using the following command, which was successful

```
gcloud auth configure-docker XXXXXX
docker pull  XXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Did you turn off the internet access? Check https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/routes-firewall

Comment: I confirmed the network permissions. There's no problem.
But when I try to pull the image locally。Got the same error as dataflow.
When I ran the following command and then did a docker pull, it successfully pulled the image。
gcloud auth configure-docker asia-docker.pkg.dev

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#access_images_for_projects_with_a_trusted_image_policy You have to make sure the dataflow service account can access your registry.

Comment: thank you so much .I can confirm that my service account has access to the current project's artifact registry, but my image exists in another project's artifact 
 registry, and I don't know how to configure service account permissions so that he can access the other project's artifact   registry.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#worker-service-account you need grant the worker service account to access the other project's artifact registry: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#basic

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, your advice is much appreciated and it's an honor to talk to you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you dont have access to the the cloud artifact registry, can you check if you have read permission on the IAM roles for artifact registry. Or if you are using Service Account, pls check if it has the required read permission.

Comment: I checked the permissions and it seems to have access to the artifact registry。 But one problem is that my dataflow is running in project A, but the artifact registry is in project B. I don't know if the permission is still valid across projects

Comment: My image address is asia-docker.pkg.dev/projeceA/......., But when I confirm the job log, the address of the image he pulled automatically changes to asia-docker.pkg.dev/v2/projeceA/...... , i just don.t know what is happening

Answer (score -1):

I need  resource "google_artifact_registry_repository_iam_binding" "reader"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Which serviceAccount did you give access to? was it service-agent or a service account of dataflow pipeline workload?